# How to shift a list to right by one element [1, 2, 3, 4] -> [4, 1, 2, 3] ? And to left [1, 2, 3, 4] -> [2, 3, 4, 1]?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a basic bubble sort and I am still quite new to programming and so my code is probably not that efficient or well designed. My Code:

```
elif n == -1:
        if numbers[n] > numbers[m]:
            for i in range(len(numbers) - 1):
                numbers2[i + 1] = numbers[i] and numbers[i] != numbers2[i + 1]


            print (numbers)
            print (numbers2)
            print (n)
            print (m)
            print (i)

            if i == len(numbers)-1:
                numbers = numbers2
                n += 1
                m += 1
```

I have come across an error in the loop as if you enter: 142, 324, 23123, 645, 643 it will push 23123 to the right but the rest of the numbers will be in descending order. Now because this was a problem I tried to solve this by making a new if statement to check the last and first number, then it would have to put the last number to the front [2, 1, 3] --> [3, 2, 1]. But when doing this i used a for loop without the: - and numbers[i] != numbers2[i + 1] - (see problem), this ended up changing the whole line of numbers into the first number in the list.

```
['23', '431', '63451', '234', '435']

['23', '23', '63451', '234', '435']
['23', '23', '63451', '234', '435']
-1
0
0
['23', '23', '23', '234', '435']
['23', '23', '23', '234', '435']
-1
0
1
['23', '23', '23', '23', '435']
['23', '23', '23', '23', '435']
-1
0
2
['23', '23', '23', '23', '23']
```

I added the second list but then I tried the code above and i get this error:

```
if numbers[n] > numbers[m]:
```

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'bool' and 'str'

So I searched to see if I could put a but in instead of the and but I found nothing. Sorry for being a long question.

Comment: Please take some time to create a [mcve] with only the code that's directly relevant to your question. Showing us all your code makes for an overly long question.

Comment: First of all, put replace `input(...)` with `int(input(...))` to get numbers, not strings.

Comment: Please read @JohnKugelman's message. You didn't ask about this, but you may have a problem here (a Python gotcha):
`numbers=[]
numbers2=numbers
numbers.append(1)
print(numbers2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve this is via using ***list slicing*** feature as:

**Move Right**

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> my_list[-1:] + my_list[:-1]
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Move Left**

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> my_list[1:] + my_list[:1]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

You can join these logic in a single **custom function to shift left and right** as:

```
def shift_list(my_list, shift_by):
    return my_list[shift_by:] + my_list[:shift_by]
```

In the above `shift_list` function, for:

- **shifting left**: pass positive integer `n` to shift left by `n` steps
- **shifting right**: pass negative integer `-n` to shift right by `n` steps

Sample Run:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# Shift left by "1" step
>>> shift_list(my_list, 1)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]

# Shift left by "2" step
>>> shift_list(my_list, 2)
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]

# Shift right by "1" step
>>> shift_list(my_list, -1)
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]

# Shift right by "2" step
>>> shift_list(my_list, -2)
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

---

As an ***alternative***, you may also use [**`itertools.cycle`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) with *list comprehension* and [**`next`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next). It is little complicated than above solution, but still a way simpler than yours:

**Move Right**

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> my_cycle = cycle(my_list[::-1])
>>> [next(my_cycle) for i in range(len(my_list)+1)][::-1][:-1]
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Move Left**

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> my_cycle = cycle(my_list)
>>> [next(my_cycle) for i in range(len(my_list)+1)][1:]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```